# Is it possible to make an Android input method which employs an existing one?

Tags: android, input

I want to make an app that is able to process the user input as they type it in, but allow them to enter text using their chosen input method. (This is not some nasty keylogger or anything, don't worry!).
Is this possible?

Comment: Android discourage that. please refer my ansver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422604/automatically-reading-in-a-single-character-from-user-input-android/ Actually android is really concerned about keylogers, so intercepting existing input method in normal way may be impossible on some devices(versions) of android