# Automatically reading in a single character from user input Android

Tags: android, input

I can't seem to find a way to do this: I want to store a single character from a user from the keyboard as part of the user input, as soon as they enter it. I don't need a text field or submit button. Prompt the user to type a character from the keyboard and store it as a char or string.

Any links for help?

Comment: when do want to show the keyboard? what is the problem of usiing edittext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catching keyboard events on android without a edittext is bad practice, existing solutions will not work on some devices, consider creating your keyboard widget

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html

```
    KeyboardView mKeyboardView;  
    Keyboard mNumberKeyboard; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        mNumberKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);  
        mKeyboardView=(KeyboardView) this.findViewById(R.id.num_keyboard);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mNumberKeyboard);
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onKey(int arg0, int[] arg1) {
                     SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreferences", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
 edit.putInt("key", arg0);
edit.commit();
            }

            @Override public void onPress(int primaryCode) {}
            @Override public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {}
            @Override public void onText(CharSequence text) {}
            @Override public void swipeDown() {}
            @Override public void swipeLeft() {}
            @Override public void swipeRight() {}
            @Override public void swipeUp() {}

        });

    }
```

Comment: Great. How would you automatically store it from a text field? As soon as they enter a character.

Comment: What does the R.id.num_keyboard and R.xml refer to?

Comment: It is xml keyboard layout for your keyboard. Please refer this link http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Comment: Why do I need to create a new keyboard layout? Can't I use the default one?

Comment: AKAIK you cant, but you can just copy android native xml. May be others will correct me